# Test Class Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: apex, soql, code-coverage

This is the first time I have messed with test classes, so there may be something I am simply overlooking. However, I am trying to test a simple class but am only getting an out of bounds exception as a result of the SOQL statement returning blank. After plugging the same SOQL statement into the developer console, I receive what was originally expected. Thanks for the help, I'll leave the little code that I'm referring to below.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Tactic_Contact__c> searchTacticContacts(String PCID)
{
    List<Tactic_Contact__c> startList = [SELECT Tactic_Name__c, Tactic_Contact__c.Project_Contact__r.Name FROM Tactic_Contact__c WHERE Tactic_Contact__c.Project_Contact__r.Name = :PCID];
    return startList;
}
```

```
@IsTest
static void searchTacticContactsTest()
{
    List<Tactic_Contact__c> TList = (RelatedContacts.searchTacticContacts('PCID-063815'));
    System.assertEquals('PCID-063815', TList.get(0).Project_Contact__r.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In unit tests, there are 3 phases.

1. Create test data
2. Execute the method you want to test
3. Gather the results, and make assertions

You're doing #2 and #3, but you've skipped over #1.

You are responsible for creating the data that your test needs (so that it can run). Tests are run isolated from "real" data by default, and this is a good thing. The exception to this is data for "setup objects" like `User`, `Profile`, `RecordType`, and a handful of others, which are available in tests without needing to do anything on your part.

So in this case, you need to:

- Create a test `Contact` and insert it
- Create a test `Tactic_Contact__c` record, relate it to your test Contact, and insert it

Then, you'll be able to call the method you want to test, `RelatedContacts.searchTacticContacts()`

Comment: The next things you should look at after this are: 1) Use a `@testSetup` annotated method to handle setting up the test data. Not a big issue for this test, but it's a good habit to get into. 2) Make more tests! Testing a lot of different scenarios helps ensure that your code is robust, and will naturally lead to high coverage. I'd definitely suggest making a specific test for when your query returns 0 rows (the list you get back should be empty and you shouldn't run into any exceptions).

Comment: Works great, thank you very much. I'll be sure to do more reading on the subject. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.